# Setting up a music files server

Tags: windows, ftp, file-sharing, cloud, file-server

My friends and I want a to setup a server where we can just dump all our music files. I would use my computer for the storage space, and my friend (who lives somewhere else) should be able to access the server and listen to the music stored on the server. I was thinking apache server but that *might* be overkill, not sure. Then I thought FileZilla, but that is an FTP server and my friends would have to download the file to listen to and it might be a little slow.

Rather it's just like your music library in the cloud..kind of....

I'm running a Windows 8 machine....dual core..kinda old but I don't think that'll be too much of a problem. Any ideas on how to best accomplish this task?

Comment: What about setting the remote access !

Comment: @Buscar웃 what exactly do you mean? Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Well, you asked for ideas. So I say try the remote access, since the files will be on your computer, and you friend could access them there.

Comment: @Buscar웃 well I was asking about how it would work and things of that nature

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question see the FAQ.

Comment: @Buscar웃 O.o...i really don't understand how I could possibly be clearer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sharing resources across a small team](http://superuser.com/questions/387117/sharing-resources-across-a-small-team)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache is a HTTP server. It means it's for websites, not file streaming. It just won't work.

The easiest solution for your problem is probably [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/). Just create an account and send your friend a referrer link, after he registers using that link you'll both get 500 MB extra space (that's 2,5 GB for free). Then you both install the Dropbox app. One of you creates a folder and shares it using Dropbox's sharing option. Any time one of you drops a file into the shared folder, it will be synced to second one's computer.

There are many other solutions like that, for example [SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com) or [Box.com](https://www.box.com/), although Dropbox is my preferred one.

This approach has one drawback: all files will be synced between your computers, it means those will take up hard disk space on both computers. But storage space is cheap nowadays and there's a number of advantages: both of you have instant file access with zero waiting time (which just can't be achieved with file streaming over the net), not to mention that you don't have to set up a separate machine and don't have to spend a penny on entire thing.

By the way, setting up an always-on server on a retired PC is never a good idea. Standard PC PSUs aren't designed for constant usage and will die very quickly. You also need some space for a PC that will always generate some irritating noise, gather dust (which kills fans) and consume electricity.

Comment: yah we thought dropbox and stuff but we collectively have 200GB of music and no money lol. Don't think that would work for us

Comment: Well, "no money" means "no electricity", and also "no dedicated server". Servers need power ;)